# Property element and attribute tag syntax

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a simple Label element and I code it in 2 ways.

Approach 1: I use attribute syntax for Converter attribute of Binding markup extension. The Converter attribute is in curly braces {}.

```
<Label Text="Flag Background" BackgroundColor="{Binding Source={x:Reference switch3}, Path=IsToggled, Converter={StaticResource boolToColor}}"></Label>
```

Approach 2: I use property-element tag for Converter attribute; It is OK.

```
<Label>
    <Label.Text>
      <Binding Source="{x:Reference switch3}" Path="IsToggled">
        <Binding.Converter>
          <toolkit:BoolToStringConverter FalseText="Red" TrueText="Lime"></toolkit:BoolToStringConverter>
        </Binding.Converter>
      </Binding>
    </Label.Text>

  </Label>
```

However, I cannot make Source as a property-element tag. I do not understand why I cannot use property-element tag for Source. Please explain.

```
<Label>
    <Label.Text>
      <Binding.Source>
          ...
      </Binding.Source>
    </Label.Text>

  </Label>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can, you just forgot binding itself:

```
<Label>
    <Label.Text>
        <Binding>
            <Binding.Source>...</Binding.Source>
        </Binding>
    </Label.Text>
</Label>
```

Comment: Evk, thank you for your reply. Can you please explain why I need a wrapping <Bind> tags for the <Binding.Source> property-element tags?

Comment: Because you actually assign Binding object to Label.Text property.  You can also assign String or other kind of supported objects, but you have to specify which. In this case you create Binding object, set its Source property, and set to Label.Text. You could do exactly the same in code without xaml.